# Python: How can I remove repeated-disordered sublists and monotonous sublists in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, set

I've seen some questions here very related but their answer doesn't work for me. I have a list of lists where 1) some sublists are repeated but their elements may be disordered, 2) and some sublists contain monotonous elements but of different lengths. For example

```
g = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 2], [9, 0, 1], [4, 3, 2]]
```

The output should be, naturally according to my question:

```
g = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [9, 0, 1], [4, 3, 2]]
```

I've tried with set. It works for repeated-disordered sublists but it treats sublists with monotonous elements of different lengths as the same.

Comment: Try it with a `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set` + sorted `tuples` in a `set comprehension`

```
>>> g = {tuple(sorted(x)) for x in g}
{(0, 1, 9), (1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)}
```

If you *really* need a list of lists as output, just transform through list comprehension

```
>>> g_list = [list(x) for x in g]
[[0, 1, 9], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a sorted tuple as your hash:

```
>>> g = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 2], [9, 0, 1], [4, 3, 2]]
>>> result = []
>>> seen = set()
>>> for x in g:
...     hsh = tuple(sorted(x))
...     if hsh not in seen:
...         result.append(x)
...         seen.add(hsh)
...
>>> result
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [9, 0, 1], [4, 3, 2]]
```

If your sublists are small, this should be speedy enough, and at least the logic is clear.

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter, you could try this:

```
list(map(list,(set(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)),g)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

List Comprehension + Unpacking:

```
print([*{*[tuple(sorted(i)) for i in g]}])
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1, 9), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1)]
```

If you want the elements to be a list do:

```
print([list(i) for i in {*[tuple(sorted(i)) for i in g]}])
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 9], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Comment: U9-Forward what is that * between list and set brackets .?

Comment: @PIG `*` is unpacking, Check these two links: http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/tuple_unpack.html and http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html